# How to run Oracle pl/sql or select query within a case statement in unix shell script

Tags: sql, bash, oracle, shell, unix

I am trying to run select statement within case statement in Unix Shell script, but getting unexpected end of file error.
I want to run particular select statement depending on the output of previous sql script ran in shell script. The output from previous sql script is spooled to a log, required pattern is fetched into a variable, which is used in case statement.
My script

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
exec > check_company_details.log 2>&1

sqlplus username/password@database << EOF
@check_company_details.sql $1 
exit;
EOF
pool=$(cat company.log | grep dbPool | awk {'print $5'})
#everything is working till above steps
#if sqlplus command is removed from below case statements, correct output of echo is returned.
case $pool in
        dbpool1) 
                echo "DBPool is POOL1"
                sqlplus username/password@database<<EOF
                select name from v\$database;
                exit;
                EOF
                ;;
        dbpool2)
                echo "DBPool is POOL1"
                sqlplus username/password@database<<EOF
                select name from v\$database;
                exit;
                EOF
                ;;
        dbpool3)
                echo "DBPool is DC4POOL1"
                sqlplus username/password@database<<EOF
                select name from v\$database;
                exit;
                EOF
                ;;
            *)
                echo No Results
                ;;
esac
```

Error message:

```
*./check_company_details.sh: line 37: syntax error: unexpected end of file*
```

Comment: Is there really an asterisk right after they keyword `esac` right at the end of your code? What happens if you delete it?

Comment: No, there is no asterisk(*) after esac, i will edit the code, thank you for highlighting

Answer (score 2):

A here doc end string should not have leading whitespace. This means you should rewrite

```
    dbpool3)
            echo "DBPool is DC4POOL1"
            sqlplus username/password@database<<EOF
            select name from v\$database;
            exit;
            EOF
```

as

```
    dbpool3)
            echo "DBPool is DC4POOL1"
            sqlplus username/password@database<<EOF
            select name from v\$database;
            exit;
EOF
```

and the same goes for the other cases.

You should also say `fgrep dbPool company.log` instead of needlessly using `cat` and instead of using `grep` when you are not feeding in a regex. You also have the quotes around your awk script in a weird place; it works but it's not what it should be.

```
pool=$(cat company.log | grep dbPool | awk {'print $5'})
```

becomes

```
pool=$(fgrep dbPool company.log | awk '{print $5}')
```

You should not expand `$pool` without quoting it, e.g. it should be `case "$pool" in`. Even if you think it won't have spaces in the variable you should do this for safety.

You should get in to the habit of checking all of your shell scripts with [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net) whether they work or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't require a `case` block. You could use an `if else` statement with pool variable.

```
if [ "$pool" = "dbpool1" ] || [ "$pool" = "dbpool2" ] || [ "$pool" = "dbpool3" ]
then
echo "DBPool is ${pool}"
sqlplus username/password@database<<EOF
select name from v\$database;
exit
EOF

else 
  echo "No Results"
fi
```